# Where does Google Script execute? On server or client?

Tags: google-apps-script

For Google Script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) here, could you please share me that these scripts are executed on the server side (run on Google machine) or client side (run on my computer when I use my browser)?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Your scripts run on Google's servers. Please check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

`*.gs` files are server side
`*.html` are client side