# I am getting a reference error regards to gapi

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, referenceerror

I am getting a reference error when trying to execute this block of code. It refers to the gapi part.

Here is a link to my script editor:

```js
const spreadsheetId = "1VMb92O3imLG9nLLVbz5-ypZfnrztSO0Co4CTzj_Fs0U";
const sourceSheetName = "Time Flies Data";
const destinationSheetName = "TF";
const extractColumns = [11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]; // "A,K,B,J" in order.
const transpose = (ar) => ar[0].map((_, i) => ar.map(r => r[i]));
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  range: sourceSheetName
}).then((res) => {
  const transposedValues = transpose(res.result.values);
  const extractedColumns = extractColumns.map(c => transposedValues[c - 1]);
  const resultValues = transpose(extractedColumns);
  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: destinationSheetName,
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"
  }, {
    values: resultValues
  }).then((r) => {
    console.log(res.result.values)
  }, function(er) {
    console.error(er.result.error.message);
  })
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err.result.error.message);
});
```

My code will not execute until this problem is fixed.

Comment: Maybe unblock the link so people can see!

Comment: What exactly is the error and which line of code is producing it?

Comment: I edited the post so now you can see the code

Comment: a reference error in line 8 with the gapi part causing it

Comment: ReferenceError: gapi is not defined (line 8, file "Code"

Comment: Where is this code executing? Where do you see the error reported (browser console or somewhere else)?

Comment: It is executing in google sheets in the script editor when I transpose it, this is showing up  in my script editor tab

Comment: gapi is a google clientside library.  Google Apps Script runs on a server. Read this: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

Answer (score 1):

`gapi` is a "client" side library(browser). Google apps script [runs on the "server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729607). It is not possible to run client side libraries on the server without reworking the entire library to suit  the server environment.

To access/modify Google sheets in server using apps script, you'd use inbuilt server side libraries like [`Spreadsheet service`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet). See:

- [Codelabs fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/fundamentals-codelabs)
- [Tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)